# Replace into MySql problema con clave foranea

Tags: mysql, insert

estoy haciendo un insert en mysql y buscando en internet me encontre con el replace into que si el registro existe lo borra e ingresa el nuevo, ahora lo intente en mysql y me dio error de clave foranea ya que el registro esta asociado a otra tabla,como debe ser la estructura de la clave foranea para que se pueda ejecutar el replace into.

**error:** #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`u261045981_app`.`PERSONAS`, CONSTRAINT `PERSONAS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PA_PAIS_ID`) REFERENCES `PAISES` (`PA_PAIS_ID`))

el insert lo hago a una tabla llamada paises que esta asociada a personas

**Estructura de tablas**

```
CREATE TABLE `PAISES` (
`PA_PAIS_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`PA_NOMBRE` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`PA_MONEDA` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`PA_CODIGO_ISO` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`PA_DECIMALES` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`PA_SEPARADOR_DECIMAL` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
 COMMENT='Paises en los que estara disponible la aplicacion';

 ALTER TABLE `PAISES`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`PA_PAIS_ID`);

 CREATE TABLE `PERSONAS` (
`PE_USU_ID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id incremental del usuario',
`PA_PAIS_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'FK tabla pais, permite 
 asociar pais al usuario',
`PE_NOMBRE` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`PE_CORREO` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 
 'correo de la persona, campo unico y usuario que se pide al iniciar 
 sesion',
 `PE_CLAVE` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 
  clave del usuario',
 `PE_ESTADO` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'estado del usuario, 1 
  es activo y 0 es inactivo y no puede ingresar a la aplicacion',
  `PE_FECHA_CREACION` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON 
  UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'fecha en la cual se crea la 
  cuenta del usuario'
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
 COMMENT='Tabla donde se almacena los datos de los usuarios';


 ALTER TABLE `PERSONAS`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`PE_USU_ID`),
 ADD KEY `PA_PAIS_ID` (`PA_PAIS_ID`);

 ALTER TABLE `PERSONAS`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `PERSONAS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PA_PAIS_ID`) 
 REFERENCES `PAISES` (`PA_PAIS_ID`);
```

**Por ultimo el insert a tabla paises**

```
REPLACE INTO `PAISES` (`PA_PAIS_ID`, `PA_NOMBRE`, `PA_MONEDA`,`PA_CODIGO_ISO`, `PA_DECIMALES`, `PA_SEPARADOR_DECIMAL`) 
VALUES  (1, 'Chile', 'Peso Chileno', 'Clp', 0, NULL);
```

Comment: El problema es que replace borra el registro, y al borrar, tu clave foranea en la tabla personas se torna invalida. Creo que no deberias usar replace en este caso

Comment: @gbianchi entonces el replace me serviria solo en tablas que su pk no sea fk en otra tabla?

Comment: El replace por ahi te serviria para la tabla personas. pero en la tabla paises, no deberias reemplazar una clave ya existente. Solo deberias hacer update, insert de claves nuevas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dice [la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), al crear tu llave foránea puedes decirle cuál será su comportamiento si cambia la referencia.

La acción referencial puede ser:

```
ON DELETE [RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT]
ON UPDATE [RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT]
```

Si no le pones ninguna acción referencial, por defecto se asume RESTRICT. Por lo tanto, tu declaración

```
ALTER TABLE `PERSONAS`
ADD CONSTRAINT `PERSONAS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PA_PAIS_ID`) 
REFERENCES `PAISES` (`PA_PAIS_ID`);
```

Equivale a

```
ALTER TABLE `PERSONAS`
ADD CONSTRAINT `PERSONAS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PA_PAIS_ID`) 
REFERENCES `PAISES` (`PA_PAIS_ID`)
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Si tú quieres permitir modificaciones en PAISES, tienes que decirle explícitamente qué quieres que ocurra cuando haces la modificación. Mientras esa acción -por defecto- sea `RESTRICT` ocurrirá lo que ves ahora. El motor de MySQL te impide modificar la tabla referenciada porque te pone en el escenario más seguro.

Me parece que, para tu caso de uso, lo único que te sirve es hacer UPDATE en la tabla PAISES, ya que un replace siempre va a borrar la fila e insertar otra, perdiéndose en el camino la integridad referencial. Por lo mismo, debieras definir tu clave como:

```
ALTER TABLE `PERSONAS`
ADD CONSTRAINT `PERSONAS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`PA_PAIS_ID`) 
REFERENCES `PAISES` (`PA_PAIS_ID`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Como tú quieres reemplazar valores, me imagino que no sabes a priori si la fila existe, y por eso usas replace para evitar insertar una fila que ya existe. En ese caso, lo que ahora haces con

```
REPLACE INTO `PAISES` (`PA_PAIS_ID`, `PA_NOMBRE`, `PA_MONEDA`,`PA_CODIGO_ISO`, `PA_DECIMALES`, `PA_SEPARADOR_DECIMAL`) 
VALUES  (1, 'Chile', 'Peso Chileno', 'Clp', 0, NULL);
```

Puedes hacerlo con

```
INSERT INTO `PAISES` (`PA_PAIS_ID`, `PA_NOMBRE`, `PA_MONEDA`,`PA_CODIGO_ISO`, `PA_DECIMALES`, `PA_SEPARADOR_DECIMAL`) 
VALUES  (1, 'Chile', 'Peso Chileno', 'Clp', 0, NULL)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
PA_PAIS_ID=1,
PA_NOMBRE='Chile',
PA_MONEDA='Peso Chileno',
PA_CODIGO_ISO='Clp',
PA_DECIMALES=0,
PA_SEPARADOR_DECIMAL=null;
```

**Edit, para mayor abundamiento**

Cuando digo que:

> un replace siempre va a borrar la fila e insertar otra,
>   perdiéndose en el camino la integridad referencial

Me refiero a que si permites la eliminación de un registro que es referenciado por otra tabla, tendrías que definir que `ON DELETE` esa tabla borre la fila `ON DELETE CASCADE` (lo que obviamente no quieres) o que deje ese campo como null `ON DELETE SET NULL`. Esto último conservará la fila o registro en la tabla `PERSONAS`, pero esa persona quedará sin nacionalidad y ese registro no va a recuperar su nacionalidad aunque vuelvas a insertar el país original. Simplemente, al dejarlo en NULL, queda desvinculado de la tabla referenciada. La tabla `PERSONAS` no puede tener registros con países que no existan en la tabla referenciada, pero sí podría tener registros sin país, y eso -como dije- te va a ir matando la integridad referencial hasta que en un momento ninguna persona tenga país.